# How can my Python Tensorflow program print what device { CPU, GPU, TPU } it is using?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, kaggle

I'm trying to run a Deep Neural Net segmentation program, written in Python/Tensorflow running under Kaggle.  I'm trying to understand how to control the device used in background runs [SAVE VERSION].  The first step is being able to see what device(s) I *am* running on -- CPU, GPU or TPU.  How can my Python program determine which device(s) are currently in use?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to answer your question. The simplest is to check what devices are available to you:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  devices = sess.list_devices()
```

If you want to know some more details about each of the devices you can run [`tf.test.gpu_device_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/gpu_device_name) to get the name of GPU device (or any other allocated).

Comment: thanks.   Two problems:   First, I had to change the definition of sess to ```tf.compat.v1.Session()```.   Second, while it correctly lists GPU devices when I have GPU enable, but **does not** list TPU devices when they are enables.   Is this because TPUs are a Tensorflow 2.0 feature?

Comment: Also, ```tf.config.list_physical_devices(device_type=None)``` doesn't show TPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
def running_on_TPU():
    try:
        tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver() # TPU detection
        tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
        tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
        strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
        return True
    except:
        return False

print( "running_on_TPU", running_on_TPU(), file = sys.stderr )
```